# how do I remove a filesystem from a Solaris liveupgrade BE

Tags: solaris, zfs, zones

I have a spare disk on my T5440 Solaris10 box that I want to use for extra ZFS filesystems

The problem is that this disk was mounted in my original OS installation - but I carried it a live upgrade and the mount point for 'carried over' into the new boot environment (BE)

So when I try and create a zpool on this disk - Solaris complains that that it is in use ....

How can I get c0t0d0 into a state that I can newfs it or create a zpool on it?

```
root@solaris>zpool create -f spare_pool c0t0d0
invalid vdev specification
the following errors must be manually repaired:
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s7 is in use for live upgrade /export/home. 
Please see   ludelete(1M).
root@solaris>


root@solaris>lustatus
Boot Environment           Is       Active Active    Can    Copy      
Name                       Complete Now    On Reboot Delete Status    
-------------------------- -------- ------ --------- ------ ----------
new_zfs_BE                 yes      yes    yes       no     -         



root@solaris>lufslist new_zfs_BE
           boot environment name: new_zfs_BE
           This boot environment is currently active.
           This boot environment will be active on next system boot.

Filesystem              fstype    device size Mounted on          Mount     Options
----------------------- -------- ------------ ------------------- --------------
/dev/zvol/dsk/rpool2/swap swap      34359738368 -                   -
rpool2/ROOT/new_zfs_BE  zfs        5213962240 /                   -
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s7       ufs      121010061312 /export/home        -
rpool2                  zfs       42872619520 /rpool2             -
```

Comment: You only have the one BE?  The `new_zfs_BE`?  Is `/export/home` in use?

Answer (score 0):

In your case /export/home is already mounted from rpool2 and then again trying from /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s7 because of this you will not able to delete the BE or patched the BE.

To recover from this issue hand edit /etc/lu/ICF.* file and delete below file.

/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s7       ufs      121010061312 /export/home        -

And then try to create your pool.